# Forwarding a request to a specific frame

Tags: jsp, servlets

does anyone know how to forward a request to a specific frame?

I use:

```
    dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/servlet/MyServlet" );
    dispatcher.forward( request, response );
```

Is there any way to define a target frame (TARGET='myFrame') in such a
request forwarding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to specify the `target` from the server side on. Imagine what would happen if it was possible to specify a `target="_blank"` from the server side on.

You'd need to specify it in the client side. You can specify the `target` attribute in `<form>` and `<a>` elements whose `action` or `href` points to the servlet in question.

As an alternative, you could go for a frameless ajax based approach. In JavaScript it's possible to traverse/manipulate the HTML DOM tree dynamically based on the servlet response. Frames are too 90's anyway.